# Routing resource show page to a generic url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm sending users, once logged into my app to the standard `users#show` page.

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

But rather than the URL showing `/users/50` I'd like it to just show a generic `/welcome`. I still need access to a users data in the view so I can use things like `<%= @user.name %>`.

Is that straightforward?

Comment: Is @user meant to be the logged-in user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it's straightforward. If `@user` is the logged-in user, then you must be storing a session cookie somewhere. Just use that to set the user. Assuming your session cookie stores the user's name, you'd have something like this:

```
def welcome
  @user = User.find_by_name(session[:user])
  # other controller code
end
```

Normally you wouldn't handle the session cookie directly like this, but instead set `current_user` in `ApplicationController` and refer to that. A `before_filter` is a good way to set that up, so that `current_user` is available in all controllers:

```
before_filter :initialize_user

def initialize_user
   @current_user = User.find_by_name(session[:user]) if session[:user]
end
```

Then you can just set `@user` like this:

```
def welcome
  @user = current_user
  # other controller code
end
```

There are other ways to do this, but whatever you do you'll need to have a session cookie set somewhere in order for this to work (since no info about the user is stored in the welcome url).

Comment: Brilliant thanks, that's working perfectly. So simple, I was thinking about it the wrong way.